# Using postgis and mongodb django

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql, postgis, djongo

I use django (2, 1, 5, 'final', 0).

My problem, i try to store an address model in postgresql, all the others models (auth, products...) in mongodb engine with the djongo package.
the models stored in app => geolocalise :

```
class Address(models.Model):

    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="France")
    #the postgis entry
    location = models.PointField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField( default=0)
    longitude = models.FloatField( default=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024,blank=True)
    #user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1} - {2}".format(self.line1, self.postalcode, self.city)
```

here my settings py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'djongo',
  'NAME': 'DBNAME',
  'USER': 'USER',
  'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD'},

'postgresql': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
  'NAME': 'DBNAME',
  'USER': 'USER',
  'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD'}}
```

But when i do my migrations i don't know why the database is store in mongodb.

I've try a configuration in a router.py which i found on stackoverflow but it's isn't working:

```
class GeolocaliseRouter(object):
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'geolocalise':
        return 'postgresql'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'geolocalise':
        return 'postgresql'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'geolocalise' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'geolocalise':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'geolocalise':
        return db == 'postgresql'
    return None
```

I've tested multiple configuration but anytimes i do the migration the model is in mongodb or all the models of my project go in postgresql....

I'm new in django and thank you for any futher assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

So after many search i can set the migration with 2 router

geolocalise.router

```
geolocalise = ['geolocalise']

class GeolocaliseRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in geolocalise:
            return 'postgresql'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in geolocalise:
            return 'postgresql'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self,obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in geolocalise and \
           obj2._meta.app_label in geolocalise:
           return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self,db, model):
        if db == 'postgresql':
            if model._meta.app_label in geolocalise:
                return True
        elif model._meta.app_label in geolocalise:
            return False
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in geolocalise:
            return db == 'postgresql'
        return None
```

and for mongo

```
app = ['api','admin', 'booking', 'categories', 'notification', 'promocodes', 'publicity', 'reviews', 'space','transactions']


class DefaultRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in app:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in app:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self,obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in app and \
           obj2._meta.app_label in app:
           return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self,db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            if model._meta.app_label in app:
                return True
        elif model._meta.app_label in app:
            return False
        return None


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in app:
            return db == 'default'
        return None
```

update the setting.py by adding

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['backend.router.DefaultRouter', 'geolocalise.router.GeolocaliseRouter', ]
```

**EDIT**

My migration is apply by this command:

```
python3 manage.py migrate geolocalise --database postgresql
```

But my foreign key is not working properly cause django doesn't handle relations between two differents databases... One day lost.

more infos here: [Unable to save with save_model using database router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579231/unable-to-save-with-save-model-using-database-router)